# Range-based for loop: why does it compile with vector<int>, but not vector<bool>?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am seeing a situation where changing the type of vector elements from `int` to `bool` makes the code stop compiling. What am I missing?

This code compiles fine:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v(10);
    for (auto& e : v)   e = 1;
}
```

While for this code, the compiler (VC++ 2017) complains about constness mismatch:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<bool> v(10);
    for (auto& e : v)   e = true;
}
```

I realize that switching to `auto&&` fixes the problem, but I would appreciate a good explanation as to why.

Comment: You can't take a reference to the elements with the `std::vector<bool>` specialization.

Comment: [`std::vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) is special. Implementations are allowed to specialize it such that each `bool` takes 1 bit. But to achieve this, it needs to break many guarantees and expectations of `std::vector`. Many people would say that this decision was a mistake, notably because it breaks code like the one you wrote.